# Right align ComponentRenderer in a Vaadin TreeGrid

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

It is possible to align text content in a Vaadin TreeGrid column using setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.END), however this does not work if the column is using a ComponentRenderer, in my case it is rendering a MenuBar component.

Does anyone know if it is possible to right align a ComponentRenderer without resorting to a template or wrapping it in a HorizontalLayout?

Comment: How does your code look like? By the way, extensive use of ComponentRenderer can lead to performance issues.

Comment: If your component does not have content in shadow DOM and thus outside of scope of this style setting, then the problem most likely is that you have not set 100% width to your component. I.e. it is right aligned, but you do not see it as right edge is not at the Grid cell edge.

Comment: I tried setting the width of the component to 100% without success. The workaround is to wrap it in a HorizontalLayout and then set the layouts width to 100%. 
In my case the table will only hold a few 10's of rows and so performance is not an issue.